# Dom Node - getChildNodes() method doesn't seem to work

Tags: xml, dom, groovy, soapui

I am using the following code to get the Child nodes of an xml request tag. But both node1 and node2 give the same result. I don't understand why.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("StepName#Request")
def node1 = holder.getDomNode("//*:SomeTag").getChildNodes().toString()
def node2 = holder.getDomNode("//*:SomeTag").toString()
log.info node1==node2 //retuns true
```

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` representation returns the same for both cases however this doesn't means the both function returns the same. However in this case you're right and both object seems equals, I try to explain it:

[`XmlHolder.getDomNode()`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/XmlHolder.html#getDomNode(java.lang.String)) returns an object instance of
`org.w3c.dom.Node` interface. And [`Node.getChildNodes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes()) returns a instance of `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` interface which contains a list of nodes contained in this node.

As you can see in the API links above the both methods at first seems that return objects that implement different interfaces, however in this context execution the both objects are instance of: `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj` and yes they are equals.

```
def xml = '''<root>
    <SomeTag><myTag>a</myTag><myTag>b</myTag></SomeTag>
</root>
'''

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(xml)
def node1 = holder.getDomNode("//*:SomeTag").getChildNodes()
def node2 = holder.getDomNode("//*:SomeTag")

log.info (node1.getClass().getName()) // prints org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj
log.info (node2.getClass().getName()) // prints org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj

log.info node1.equals(node2) // true
```

Note that depends on the context where this code runs (there are other library implementations on the classpath etc.) the both objects could not be equal.

As you comment if you want to use only the child nodes you can iterate in this case over both objects using for example `each`:

```
def xml = '''<root>
    <SomeTag><myTag>a</myTag><myTag>b</myTag></SomeTag>
</root>
'''
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(xml)
def node1 = holder.getDomNode("//*:SomeTag").getChildNodes()
def node2 = holder.getDomNode("//*:SomeTag")

node1.each{
    log.info it.toString()
}

node2.each{
    log.info it.toString()
}
```

This code logs:

```
// node 1 each
Wed Oct 07 21:26:07 CEST 2015:INFO:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myTag>a</myTag>
Wed Oct 07 21:26:07 CEST 2015:INFO:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myTag>b</myTag>
// node 2 each
Wed Oct 07 21:26:07 CEST 2015:INFO:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myTag>a</myTag>
Wed Oct 07 21:26:07 CEST 2015:INFO:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myTag>b</myTag>
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Then how do I get only the child nodes of 'SomeTag' using 'holder'?

Comment: @EistonDsouza Did you refer something that return only the content of `<SomeTag>` without the tag itself? in the answer sample something that returns `<myTag>a</myTag><myTag>b</myTag>`?

Comment: yes, exactly :) I need only `<myTag>a</myTag><myTag>b</myTag>`

Comment: My question was, why does both of it return the same result?
`getChildNodes()`(node1) should fetch ONLY the children right? and node2 should return the parent AND the children without iterating withing the content (by using each). Now by seeing the above results, the use of `getChildNodes()` makes no difference! :) 
I say that node1==node2 should have returned a 'false' if `getChildNodes()` is a legit call to be used.